# dashed lines show in Graphical Layout but not on devices

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-canvas

I am using paint to draw a dashed line in android.

```
dashed.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 5, 5 }, 0));
```

During development, everything shows up fine in the Graphical Layout view. But when I plugin a real device, the device shows a solid line. At first I thought it was because my devices were all LG. Then I tested on a Samsung S4: same problem. Does anyone know how to fix this discrepancy? It makes no sense that the Graphical Layout is saying one thing and yet no actual device agrees with it. Any advice?

Comment: Oh, yes. I play around with the numbers in new float[] { 5, 5 }. No difference.

Comment: You can try turning off the hardware acceleration for the view. Override `disableHardwareRendering(View v) { v.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); }`.

Comment: That did it, @vikram. Do you mind posting as response so I may mark this thread as answered?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See if turning off the hardware acceleration for the view helps:

```
@Override
public static void disableHardwareRendering(View v) {

    v.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

}
```

From Android developers page on [Hardware Acceleration:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)

> Use a software layer type to force a view to be rendered in software.
>   If a view that is hardware accelerated (for instance, if your whole
>   application is hardware acclerated), is having rendering problems,
>   this is an easy way to work around limitations of the hardware
>   rendering pipeline.

Some more information about this issue on code.google: [Link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29944).

Answer (score 11):

disable hardware acceleration might be not best way, try this from [here](https://codentrick.com/cant-draw-dashed-line-in-android-with-hardware-acceleration/) :

```
Path baseline = new Path();
baseline.moveTo(0, 0);
baseline.lineTo(100, 0);
canvas.drawPath(baseline, paint);
```

Comment: This solved my problem. In my case, `canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint)` was drawing a solid line instead of a dashed one.

Comment: I did not expect this to work, but there we are. Drawing a line did not produce a dashed line, but drawing a line path with the same paint does. Crazy that basic things like drawing a dashed line does not work on some devices, bot does on others.

Answer (score 1):

If you maybe have set

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

In your **Manifest file** - reset it (set on false) or, better remove the whole line